# Mayavi, python axes INDICATOR

Tags: python, axes, mayavi, indicator

does anyone know how to switch on the axes **INDICATOR** in python code? I can switch it on when the graph is plotted, but I wanna know how to do it in code. I have found only how to switch on the axes:

```
mlab.axes()
```

but it is not the indicator (I mean that three arrows X,Y and Z)

Thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code switches on the axes indicator:

```
mlab.orientation_axes()
```